# SelectPdf Error: Could not get conversion result header. Data receive timeout. [SelectPdf Library for .NET C#]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.1, html-to-pdf, selectpdf

**Exception Message:** `Could not get conversion result header. Data receive timeout.`

C# Code:

```
        public static MemoryStream ConvertHtmlToPdf(string html)
        {
            HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();
            PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(html);
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            doc.Save(ms);
            return ms;
        }
```

Exception is happenning at line `PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(html);`

I am working in **.NET Core 3.1**, using package **"Select.Pdf.NetCore" Version="22.2.0"**.

I encountered this error with a very large HTML string( 178 pages if you do *Save As PDF* in Chrome browser). Unfortunately, I am unable to share the HTML due to data privacy concerns. However, I want to clarify that the HTML is valid and can be successfully rendered in a web browser.

Comment: you'd better to have more code snippets here so that we could reproduce the issue. a mininal reproducable sample is helpful to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what has caused the problem. Does your HTML file contain Smart Forms, any VB scripts? This may be causing the problem.